# Eventlistener not listening when removing cursor from stage

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

When i set my stage cursor to none. I can't access my shape's(`Startscreen.startButton`) eventlistener somehow. I can click it when i don't hide my cursor though.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
function initStartscreen() {
    startscreenLayer = new createjs.Container();

    createMenuCursor();

    stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove", mouseMove);
    stage.enableMouseOver(2);
    stage.cursor = 'none';

    Startscreen = new Startscreen();

    startscreenLayer.addChild(Startscreen.background);

    startscreenLayer.addChild(Startscreen.startButton);
    startscreenLayer.addChild(Startscreen.startText);

        startscreenLayer.addChild(Startscreen.highscoreButton);
        startscreenLayer.addChild(Startscreen.highscoreText);

        stage.addChildAt(startscreenLayer);

    stage.update();

    Startscreen.startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(1);
    });
}

function Startscreen() {
    this.background = new createjs.Shape();
    this.background.graphics
        .beginFill('pink')
        .drawRect(0, 0, stage.canvas.width, stage.canvas.height);

    this.startButton = new createjs.Shape();
    this.startButton.graphics
        .beginFill('#000')
        .drawRect(0, 0, 250, 50)
    this.startButton.x = (stage.canvas.width/2)-125;
    this.startButton.y = 150;
    this.startButton.name = "startButton";

    this.startText = new createjs.Text('Start', '30px Calibri', '#FFF');
    this.startText.x = this.startButton.x + 95;
    this.startText.y = this.startButton.y + 7;
}
```

Instant update:
Even if i strip everything off and just leave the `initStartscreen()` in my onload it doesn't work.

It must be some layering issue or something because i've created a backbutton in my highscores layer which works when i use it by navigating there from the main menu. But after i've played my game and go to the same page/function the back button doesn't work.

Is there a way to always get the layer i added to the top perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit to being a bit confused and I probably need clarification from you!

Do I understand that you are hiding the cursor and then expect the user to find a start-button with an "invisible" cursor?  -- Are you being mean to your users? :p

If you feel `stage.cursor='none'` is misbehaving you can use CSS to set the cursor to "none" in the latest versions of IE,FF and Chrome. In the "invisible" state, the mouse events are *still* fired. Code below and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qBw9P/

```
$("#theStageCanvas").click(function(){ $("#theStageCanvas").css("cursor","none"); });
```

Or do you have multiple stages and you want to make a bottom stage respond to click events even though there is a top stage over it?

You can turn off event listening on the top layer like this:

```
topStage.onClick=null;
topStage.onMouseDown=null;
topSstage.onMouseUp=null;
topStage.onMouseMove=null;
```

Comment: Haha, obviously i've got a bitmap following the mouseX and mouseY ;-) The things clicked are on a canvas. So jQuery isn't realling a fitting solution i'm afraid.